# Cleanup in END function

Tags: perl

My perl script uses an END function where it unlinks some temporary files. Sometimes the script gets interrupted or suspended by the user, and the temporary files don't get deleted.

What are the procedures for dealing with this in perl? The end function don't work unless the script fully runs or executes an exit or a die.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two aspects here. The first is to clean up temporary files if your program finishes more or less cleanly. For this you don't have to reinvent the wheel, simply use the core module [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Temp). It can do a lot, and one of its benefits is that it removes temporary files when the variable is garbage collected.

The other aspect is if a real program crash happens (e.g. `kill -9`). In that case your program cannot handle the cleanup itself. You'll have to rely on the operating system to do that for you. Several Linux distributions for example clean up `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` regularly. You could also write a cron job for you that assists you.

Note, however, that not all Linux distros clean up in `/tmp` (or `/var/tmp`). Others only do it during the boot process. Doing so while the machine is running is potentially dangerous (files that are still in use by programs might accidentally be deleted). There are tools like [tmpreaper](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tmpreaper-cleans-up-files-in-directories-based-on-their-age.html) that can help you with it.

If you want a rather fool-proof way then I suggest you use neither `/tmp` nor `/var/tmp` but your own sub-directory beneath one of them and use tools like `tmpreaper` for cleaning up that directory. That way you can be moderately sure that only the temporary files of your program (and not those of others) are affected by the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about /tmp. I'll just store the files there.

Answer (score 1):

`END {}` blocks only run when Perl itself decides to exit. If it exits due to a `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` (because someone pressed `Ctrl+C` on the terminal) then the block won't run.

You could catch these two signals and `exit` anyway, thus causing Perl to handle that after all. You can install a signal handler:

```
$SIG{TERM} = $SIG{INT} = sub { exit 1 };
```

There's nothing you can do about death by `SIGKILL` but that should be rare.

Answer (score 0):

On a unix system, you can still use a file after it has been deleted if the file was opened before it was deleted. If you don't actually need the file's name (or if you can adjust your code so you don't), this is the most reliable solution. Some of [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTemp)'s functions will pre-delete the temporary file for you.

Answer (score -1):

If the real program interrupt happens(e.g. kill -9, or Ctrl+C), you can specify how your program should handle it.

Search for %SIG [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and you'll find an example.

Comment: You cannot handle `SIGKILL` (which is `kill -9`) in a program. You can handle the normal `kill` though (`SIGTERM`).